# How can I extract semicolon separated values from DataGridView cell in C#

Tags: c#

[image: screenshot]

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms. as shown in screenshot I have cell in `DataGridView` which contains semicolon separated values. I have this code which creates new buttons but I am missing the part where I can assign each value in the cell to a new button.

I want to split those values (HOUSENO column) and assign each one of them to a button text on my form. Anyone knows how can I do that. Thank you

```
// I am trying to loop all those values and assign them to a new button text but I have no idea how to do it:

            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = 
                btn.Width = 162;
                btn.Height = 100;               

                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `DataSet/DataTable`, you haven't specified:

```
var row = dt.Rows[0]["HOUSENO"].ToString(); // no idea if you're returning more than one row

string[] houseNumbers = row.Split(';');

foreach(string houseNum in houseNumbers)
{
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Text = houseNum;
     btn.Width = 162;
     btn.Height = 100;               

     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) method on string.

Simple example:

```
string test = "17;25;85;24;54;32";
string[] results = test.Split(';');
foreach(string result in results)
{
    // here add buttons
}
```